# problem in calling method in webservice

Tags: webservices

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v/restAPIKeyGeneration/*')

global with sharing class APIforKeyGeneration{


    global class Account{
    public String sname;
    public String bp;

}

    @HttpPost
    global static String CallTo(Account[] account){
    system.debug('rtrtr');
    String Name;
    String BillingCity;
    for (Account i : account) {
           Name = i.sname;
           BillingCity = i.bp;
    }
    //String key = SourceMDMRestAPI.GenerateKey(account[0].Name);
    return 'key' ;
    }


}


public class SourceMDMRestAPI{
    public static string GenerateKey(Account acc){//how can i cal this method in my webservice
Account m=new Account(Name=acc.name);
    return m.id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is trying to accept an Schema.Account (a subtype of Schema.SObject), but your webserivce method is trying to pass it a custom class APIforKeyGeneration.Account. Since they're not compatible types, you're getting a compilation error.

The minimum fix you could do is to specify the custom class in the parameter:

```
global class SourceMDMRestAPI{
    global static string GenerateKey(ApiForKeyGeneration.Account acc){//how can i cal this method in my webservice
        Account m=new Account(Name=acc.sname);
        return m.id;
    }
}
```

Also, you meant to pass the entire object, so you'd want to do something like this:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v/restAPIKeyGeneration/*')

global with sharing class APIforKeyGeneration{


    global class Account{
        public String sname;
        public String bp;

    }

    @HttpPost
    global static String CallTo(Account[] account){
        system.debug('rtrtr');
        String Name;
        String BillingCity;
        for (Account i : account) {
            Name = i.sname;
            BillingCity = i.bp;
        }
        String key = SourceMDMRestAPI.GenerateKey(account[0]);
        return 'key' ;
    }
}
```

Personally, I'd consider renaming your Account class to something else to avoid confusion.